# ArgumentException for unused axis

Tags: unity

I'm creating a simple Pachinko-style game and using a single button to drop balls in. Everything is working great, but the Unity Editor is throwing an ArgumentException for the **Submit** axis "not set up", so I added it to the InputManager only for it to then throw the same error for the **Cancel** axis.

When I first started the project I deleted the default axes from the InputManager and replaced them with a single one I've called "Fire". I don't use any other axes in any of my two script.

If I select the error in the console it jumps me to BaseInput.cs

I researched this for a while, but the only solution I saw was regarding a misspelling of the axis name, but I'd like to be clear that in this case the axes involved are totally unused in my code.

Comment: Do you have a [Standalone Input Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/Manual/script-StandaloneInputModule.html) in any of your scenes, supporting interaction with your UI canvas?

Comment: Yes! I disabled that component on the EventSystem and it totally worked! Thanks so much! (Still trying to figure out how to mark your comment as the answer, though!)

EDIT: I suppose I can't mark that as an answer, so I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) for answering this! The problem was indeed caused by a Standalone Input Module on my EventSystem which was created when I added the UI Canvas. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that these inputs are needed if you want players to be able to navigate your UI using a keyboard or gamepad. This can be important for accessibility, so it's worth mapping these controls to inputs in your Input Manager.

Comment: That makes sense! In this case it was a tutorial that didn't require any UI input methods, so I had removed the default key binds because they were unnecessary.